# Can bs4 to parse tag with <style='display:none;'>?

Tags: css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, styles, display

If you browse this page `https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201808/220015/?fm=tp_index`, you will two images, when I parse it as code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import re

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201808/220015/?fm=tp_index')
soup_level2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

sections = soup_level2.find_all("img")

for section in sections:
    image = re.findall(r"(https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/[0-9]+/.+)\?[0-9]+", urljoin('https://weathernews.jp/', section['src']))

    if image:
        print(image[0])
    else:
        image = re.findall(r"(https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/[0-9]+/.+)\?[0-9]+", urljoin('https://weathernews.jp/', section.get("data-original")))
        if image:
            print(image[0])
```

I got images as below

```
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_top_img_A.jpg
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img0_A.jpg
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img1_A.jpg
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img2_A.jpg
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img5_A.png
```

In fact, there are two other images with `style="display: none;"` on page, can you help me to parse them?

```
<section id="box3" class="nodisp_zero" style="display: none;">
    <h1 id="box_ttl3" style="display: none;"></h1>
    <img style="width: 100%; display: none;" id="box_img3" alt="box3" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img3_A.jpg?1533975785">
    <figcaption id="box_caption3" style="display: none;"></figcaption>
    <div class="textarea clearfix">
        <h2 id="box_subttl3" style="display: none;"></h2>
        <div class="fontL" id="box_com3" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the html using the attributes.

**Ex:**

```
html = """<section id="box3" class="nodisp_zero" style="display: none;">
    <h1 id="box_ttl3" style="display: none;"></h1>
    <img style="width: 100%; display: none;" id="box_img3" alt="box3" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img3_A.jpg?1533975785">
    <figcaption id="box_caption3" style="display: none;"></figcaption>
    <div class="textarea clearfix">
        <h2 id="box_subttl3" style="display: none;"></h2>
        <div class="fontL" id="box_com3" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</section>"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print( soup.find("section", {"style": "display: none;"}).img["data-original"] )
```

**Output:**

```
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img3_A.jpg?1533975785
```

Comment: I need this one `https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img3_A.jpg`, then can you parse that web page? I can parse for static text, but not that page, you can view that page source, there are two images look like `*_box_img3_A.jpg, *_box_img4_A.jpg`, I want to get those URL...

Comment: Use `img["data-original"] `

Comment: No, I can't get data in <section style='dsiplay: none;'>, can you try it for me?

Comment: I added my code, can you test it for me? I want to parse including `https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img3_A.jpg` and `https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img4_A.png`.